# Load PDF from URL with Authentication

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, basic-authentication, pdfview

I want to display a `.pdf` file in `WebView` which is having authentication. The app has been rejected by Google as I am using intent to load the `WebView`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://UserName:password@myUrl", "text/html");mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `https://username:password@url` in android, unfortunately.

You have to add Basic Authorization in the Request Property in a bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String basicAuth = USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD
basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(basicAuth.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
bundle.putString("Authorization", basicAuth);
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
```

you may also need:

```
webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(<URL>);
```

Comment: I have tried using the above code. Now the browser is showing the fields for entering user name and password.